# Using Python and Google Places API, how can I get the Place_id of a specific place at a given address?

Tags: python, google-maps, google-places-api

I'd like to use Python and the Google Places API to get review data for a gas station located at 1101 E FLORENCE AVE, LOS ANGELES, CALIFORNIA 90001. When I search using the API, I get a "building" located at that address, but not the gas station. When I search for the address in the web version of Google Maps, I see that the 76 gas station is listed under "At this place."

[Screenshot of Google Maps "At this place"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfDmr.png)

How can I get the place ID of the 76 gas station that is located at the address, instead of the ID of the "building?"

Here is my code:

```py
import requests

ad = '1101 E FLORENCE AVE, LOS ANGELES, CALIFORNIA 90001' # this address does not work
# ad = '3400 san pablo ave, oakland, ca 946084234' # this address works
address = ad.replace(' ', '%20') #make sure there are no blank spaces for the URL
url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input="+ address + \
       "&inputtype=textquery&fields=place_id&key="+ API_KEY
response = requests.get(url).json()

place_ids = [] # container for place_id
for c in response['candidates']:
     place_ids.append(c)

# get the review data for the place_id
# this section gives an error since the "building" doesn't have reviews.
# however, this works using the address '3400 san pablo ave, oakland, ca 946084234'
for p in place_ids:
     url2 = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id="+c['place_id']+"&key="+API_KEY
     response2 = requests.request("GET", url2, headers={}, data={})
     reviews = response2.json()['result']['reviews']
```

The above code returns the place ID 'ChIJ9Scljph-hYARAU-0jfBmjqY', which is not the place ID for the 76 station.

Answer (score 1):

### Include The Name of the Place in your Text Input Together with the Address

As per the [Places API Find Place Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-find-place):

> *"A Find Place request takes a text input and returns a place. The input can be any kind of Places text data, such as a name, address, or phone number. The request must be a string."*

If you go down a little further in the documentation, the description of the `Input` in the **[Required Parameters](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-find-place#required-parameters)** says:

> *"The text string on which to search, for example: "restaurant" or "123 Main Street". This must be a place name, address, or category of establishments. Any other types of input can generate errors and are not guaranteed to return valid results. The Places API will return candidate matches based on this string and order the results based on their perceived relevance."*

Please know that the API is ***working as intended*** in returning the Place ID of a building in the specified address. You just need to be specific in what place you want to find. In your case, the **76 Station** in the specified address. If you want to search for **Nearby Places** in a specified location, check out [Nearby Search](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-nearby) instead.

Now to solve your issue, you only need to include `76 Station` together with the `1101 E FLORENCE AVE, LOS ANGELES, CALIFORNIA 90001` in your address input.

Your code should look like this after making the necessary changes:

```
import requests
API_KEY = 'YOUR_API_KEY_HERE'
# Just include "76 STATION AT..." in the beginning of your text query.
ad = '76 STATION AT 1101 E FLORENCE AVE, LOS ANGELES, CALIFORNIA 90001'

address = ad.replace(' ', '%20') # make sure there are no blank spaces for the URL
url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input="+ address + \
       "&inputtype=textquery&fields=place_id&key="+ API_KEY
response = requests.get(url).json()

place_ids = [] # container for place_id
for c in response['candidates']:
     place_ids.append(c)

# get the review data for the place_id
# this now return results of reviews from the 76 GAS STATION.
for p in place_ids:
     url2 = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id="+c['place_id']+"&key="+API_KEY
     response2 = requests.request("GET", url2, headers={}, data={})
     reviews = response2.json()['result']['reviews']
     # Added print here for you to see that it now works
     print(reviews)
```

> ***NOTE**: Since you tried to reference the Google Maps App, I would like to set the expectation here that the **Google Maps App** and **the Google Maps API** are different platforms, so we should expect differences in features and behaviors and should not be compared to avoid confusion. Please refer to the official [Google Maps Platform Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps) for more API information.*

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful. I think your approach will work for my current project, which looks at all gas stations, by searching for something like "gas station at [address]." Eventually, though, I'd like I'd like to expand to retail sites of all types. Other than using Nearby Search, is there a way to find all of the Places that share an address?

Comment: Glad it helped! Please do mark the answer as `accepted` if it suffices. With regards to your additional queries, we would recommend that you ask another question here in SO and I would be glad to answer it. But just for a short response, Nearby Search would actually be fine for your needs but is there any reason why you don't want to? But anyways, please do ask another question so that we could get into details.